# How to autowire service in ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm writting my application using Spring MVC.
I want to validate is e-mail exists in database when user is registering. I've written my own annotation constraint named **UniqueEmail**.

My User entity **User.java**:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @UniqueEmail(message = "E-mail is not unique")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 5, message = "size must be more 5")
    private String password;
}
```

My annotation constraint **UniqueEmail.java**:

```java
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UniqueEmail {
    String message() default "Email is exist";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

My validator **UniqueEmailValidator.java**:

```java
@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueEmail uniqueEmail) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        try {
            return userService.isExistEmail(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works in application.

When I run my test code its return NullPointerException. In my validation class **userService** is null.

I've read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html but cannot any solution.

Any idea?

**Update**

I use JUnit. **UserClassTest.java**

```java
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class UserClass {

    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void emailIsUnique() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("mail@example.com"); // I've written exist email in DB.

        Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validateProperty(user, "email");

        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        assertEquals("E-mail is not unique", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="ru.yadoka"/>

<import resource="db/db-config.xml"/>

<!-- Apache tiles -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

<!-- Mapping resources from theme -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/resources/
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: if userService is null, it means that you do not have it autowired correctly.

Comment: Are you using <context:component-scan> in your applicationcontext ?

Comment: Kiotoer - yes `<context:component-scan base-package="ru.yadoka"/>`. In my controller the userService autowired correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you have a Validator configured in your bean context. If you are bootstrapping *Validator* via *Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();* you are bypassing the Spring mechanism and you get a Validator which is not aware of Spring beans and components. Hence injection is not working. In your test you want to get hold of the Spring provided Validator.

Answer (score 3):

You can call injection all @Autowired service:

```
@Override
public void initialize(UniqueEmail uniqueEmail) {
   org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main code is working, then it should be straight forward to get your test working.
You need to use @ContextConfiguration on your test class, see this for more details:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

In general, there are 2 ways to test this:

- unit test
- integration test

For unit test, you need to create an instance of the UniqueEmailValidator and set a UserService on that instance (normally a mock UserServer).

For integration test, you need to have the spring context initialized as I mentioned above.

Comment: I've updated my post. How to create an instance of the UniqueEmailValidotor and set a UserService?

Comment: can you post the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: I've added config to post.

Comment: In the UserClassTest, where is the validator instance defined?

Comment: In the @BeforeClass, I've updated UserClassTest.java

Comment: Ok, so looks like its the way you instantiate the validators.  Since spring not doing this, it cannot wire in any services used in those classes.  Can you autowire the validator in your test class?